# Terraform EC2 has no binded port and ping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I wanted to launch an EC2 instance that I can have access to from the internet.

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "ig" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet("10.0.0.0/16", 8, count.index)
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security" {
  name   = "security"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "applications" {
  ami                    = "ami-08c40ec9ead489470"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security.id]
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.subnet.id
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.ig]
}
```

But telnet 8080 doesn't work also there is no ping response from the server. It seems I have no access to the EC2 instance from the internet.

Comment: Does your VPC have an [Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)? You need an internet gateway in order for any network interfaces in your VPC to get routable public IP addresses; otherwise they only have private IP addresses within the VPC.

Comment: (If you want to declare an Internet Gateway with Terraform then you can use [`aws_internet_gateway`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway).)

Comment: What are you running in your ec2 instance that's binded and listening on 8080

Comment: Your TF code is not even valid code, so its difficult to guess what you are actually doing and why things do not work.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I just added it, but still doesn't work. I updated the code.

Comment: @Marcin sorry, my bad, I just updated the code.

Comment: " telnet 8080 doesn't work" - what does it mean? Any errors? How do you test it? Why would your website be on port 8080? Does it actually work?

Comment: @Marcin by "doesn't work" I meant it seems the port is not exposed because it can't connect and it stucks. 8080 is just a sample. I can change it to 80 if you want.

Comment: Are you trying to ping or access the website using internet?

Comment: @Marcin both, but first I get ping to ensure I can see it from outside, then I'll work on the website.

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect to your instance from outside of AWS, as your ingress rules prohibit it due to:

```
cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
```

This limit access to only from within a VPC.

For internet access it must be

```
cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
```

Comment: I already tested by `["0.0.0.0/0"]` but still doesn't work.

Comment: @mortymacs This is the main reason. Others could be due to your multitude mistakes in your TF code, such as `vpc_id = aws_vpc.` or `from_port   = 8   to_port     = 0` (from can't be higher then to).

Comment: @mortymacs How did it go? Is it still unclear why you have problems with the connectivity?

Comment: Finally, it's been fixed :D I changed several things, Internet gateway, subnet, cidr, and now it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @mortymacs So did you change cider in SG as I wrote in the answer?